# What's the difference between object.method(); vs method(object);?

Tags: java, object, methods

In Java, what's the difference between using object.method(); vs using method(object);?

Comment: You may wish to read the official language tutorials, specifically the [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) section. Some amount of research is generally expected prior to asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object.method() --> You are calling the  method of a class (here object is a instance of that class where your method is declared)

method(object) --> your passing a object reference to a method (On which internally in the method you can use that object and can call its properties and methods);